# Scanner is skipping nextLine() starting from the 2nd object in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have created an array list with size 10. It was just fine with the first object in the array. But, then I figured out that user's input in the second object in the array got skipped. (It won't ask user to enter their name starting from the second object in the array)

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       {
        array[i] = new Homestay();
        
        System.out.println("\nEnter Customer Name");
        nama = keyboard.nextLine();
        /*prob: the second array won't ask user their name.
        if i write keyboard.nextLine(); again, it will ask 
        user's name(input), but it won't display the user's name(output).*/
```

Output:

**The first object in the array list**

Enter Customer Name /*it can ask the user's name and it can also display the output*/

Jungkook

**The second object in the array**

Enter Customer Name //this line got skipped

Enter Customer No

Comment: That is not a [mre], but your problem is probably [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/3890632)

Comment: hey khelwood thank you so much!